# Wamp tmp redirect

Tags: wamp, tmp

I would like to redirect my tmp files to another drive instead of C:/wamp/tmp I would like to redirect tmp files to `D:/tmp` or do I have to reinstall wamp on the D drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way, went in the php.ini file and changed the c:/wamp/tmp to d:/wamp/tmp.